# Erase required initializers

Tags: ios, swift

We have lots of UIView and UIViewController subclasses with custom initializers and since Xcode Beta 5 we have to spell out the `required init(coder:)` initializer for each of those subclasses to satisfy the compiler:

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
  fatalError( "NSCoding not supported")
}
```

We don't use Interface Builder or Storyboard so NSCoding compliance is not needed for our project. Is there a way to tell the compiler that it's ok if this method is not implemented without having to add the above code to every new subclass?

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't a way to tell that to the compiler. You can't even implement a layer between your subclasses and `UIView` and `UIViewController` whose sole purpose is `required init...`.

As soon as you implement the `init(frame..)` override, you must implement the `required init(coder...)`.